# Нужна ли запятая перед «с кем»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Говорит так, будто ему вообще без разницы(,) с кем идти.

> Но раз тебе совершенно плевать(,) с кем и зачем, то я пас.

Нужны ли здесь запятые?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) *Говорит так, будто ему вообще без разницы, **с кем идти**.*

В этом предложении запятая ставится **по обычным правилам** для СПП (с придаточным изъяснительным).

(2) *Но раз тебе совершенно плевать **с кем и зачЕм**, то я пас.*

Если придаточное обозначено только союзным словом (**союзными словами**), то запятая в общем случае не ставится (одно ударение в конце фразы).

(3) В то же время **авторский вариант** возможен при подчеркивании местоименных слов (два ударения):

*Но раз тебе совершенно **плевАть**, **с кем и зачЕм**, то я пас*.

В заданном предложении лучше использовать **этот вариант.**

Розенталь, пункт 4(3) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

**Примеры:**

*Нам вообще-то по большому счёту **без разницы**, кто там в постели.* Гай Юлий Орловский, 2011

Он сказал, что тут всё отстой, и делать ему тут нечего, но ему **без разницы где**, лишь бы его не трогали. О.Н. Назарова, По ту сторону сказки, 2018

*Да в общем, **плевать**, кто. Обойдусь.* [Наталья Стеркина. Не вспомнить... 2014]

*Мне **плевать**, кто он и что.* Он больше не позвонит. [Майя Кучерская. Тетя Мотя, 2012]